# How do I create a XAML storyboard animation from C++\CX?

Tags: xaml, c++-cx, win-universal-app

I've defined a Rectangle in the XAML named "MyRectangle" and when clicked I execute this code:

```
    auto animation = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Animation::DoubleAnimation();
    animation->From = 0.01;
    animation->To = 5.50;
    animation->AutoReverse = true;
    auto beginTime = Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan();
    beginTime.Duration = 0;
    animation->BeginTime = beginTime;
    auto duration = Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan();
    duration.Duration = 20000*1000;
    animation->Duration = duration;
    auto storyboard = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Animation::Storyboard();
    auto scaleTransform = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::ScaleTransform();
    MyRectangle->RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
    storyboard->SetTargetProperty(animation, "(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)");
    storyboard->SetTarget(animation, MyRectangle);
    storyboard->SetTargetName(animation, "MyRectangle");
    storyboard->SpeedRatio = 1.0;
    storyboard->Begin();
```

However, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Duration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.foundation.timespan.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) is *a time period expressed in 100-nanosecond units*. So your animation runs for 2 milliseconds. Better set `animation->Duration = TimeSpan::FromSeconds(20)` or so.

Comment: I increased it by a factor of 1000 and still nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like you didn't add the animation to the storyboard. Try calling `storyboard->Children->Append(animation);` before `storyboard->Begin();`.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the "animation" (or more animations) to the "storyboard" childrens:

storyboard->Children->Append(animation);

This is the C# equivalent:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard